# How to get value from dropdown to insert in EF CodeFirst

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, code-first

I am working on Webforms (no MVC) I have the following scenario. I want to get ID of selected text of dropdown and insert on click event. but it is showing conversion error from string to EFCode.Department.

Code

```
EmployeeDbContext db = new EmployeeDbContext();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DropDownList1.DataSource = db.Departments.ToList();
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
            }


            GridView1.DataSource = db.Departments.Include("Employees").ToList();
            GridView1.DataBind();



        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Employee emp = new Employee(){Name = TextBox1.Text,
            Gender= TextBox2.Text,
            Salary = float.Parse(TextBox3.Text),
            **Department = DropDownList1.SelectedValue**}; // error here

       db.Employees.Add()
           db.SaveChanges();
    }

public class Department
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }


    public class Employee
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public float Salary { get; set; }
        **public Department Department { get; set; }**
    }




    public class EmployeeDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Well `Department` is not a string, it is a **class**. See your code.

Comment: that is my question. how to convert string to class type

Comment: @S.Akbari `Department` is navigation property. how to set it there in in object of employee, retriving its value from dropdown.

Comment: Use object initializer just like one that you did already for `Employee`. For example: `Department = new Department
                {
                    ID = ....,Name = DropDownList1.SelectedValue,
                }`

Comment: @S.Akbari thisn going to add a new value, not getting the the value of selected item in database. I need just value of selected item, which is already in database.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use string substitute department object 
when you execute the code the relation will be int , there for you must use conversion to Int32

```
 Employee emp = new Employee(){Name = TextBox1.Text,
        Gender= TextBox2.Text,
        Salary = float.Parse(TextBox3.Text),
        Department = db.GetDepartmentByID(Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue))};
```

Comment: this throw an error, cannot convert implicitly convert type int to Project.Department

Answer (score 0):

You cant declare department as a property.. I have modified your code in the way that Name will be retrived from your department table which is in your database by using the dropDownList1.SelectValue.. Not sure whether this is your requirement..

Code:

```
       protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        Employee emp = new Employee(){
        Name =  TextBox1.Text,
        Gender=  TextBox2.Text,
        Salary = float.Parse(TextBox3.Text),
          Department = new Department() 
           {
               Name = db.Department.Where(s => s.Id == dropDownList1.SelectValue).Select(s.Name).FirstOrDefault();

           },
       };
       db.Employees.Add();
       db.SaveChanges();
       }
```

Comment: i.e, s.Name i have modified that now , the column name of your Department table.. Is that your requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Employee emp = new Employee(){Name = TextBox1.Text,
            Gender= TextBox2.Text,
            Salary = float.Parse(TextBox3.Text),
            Department = db.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == DropDownList1.SelectedValue)};
```

Comment: still problem exist

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the page load

```
if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DropDownList1.DataSource = db.Departments.ToList();
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
            }
```

You need to add this

```
if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    DropDownList1.DataSource = db.Departments.ToList();
                    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Name";
                    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID"; **//This will get the id**
                    DropDownList1.DataBind();
                }
```

Also convert to Int: (Convert.ToInt32(Dropdownlist.SelectedValue))